# Unit tests pass when run from Visual Studio 2017 Test Explorer but fails with “dotnet test” - Is there any difference between these 2 - C#, .NetCore

Tags: .net-core, nunit-3.0

I tried running the unit test cases using VS 2017 and that worked fine, but it is failing with the command line parameter "dotnet test"

[Unit tests pass with "dotnet test" but fail when run from Visual Studio 2017 Test Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679021/unit-tests-pass-with-dotnet-test-but-fail-when-run-from-visual-studio-2017-tes)

This request is completely opposite scenario for me

Error Message:
 System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Application.UnitTesting.Mock.MockInsightIPedsRepository' threw an exception.
  ----> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: . Path '', line 1, position 2.

--JsonReaderException
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberCharIntoBuffer(Char currentChar, Int32 charPos) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:line 1398
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer() in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:line 1350
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:line 1927
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs:line 1772
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs:line 1195
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 149
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:line 907
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in /*/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:line 828
   at Application.UnitTesting.Mock.MockInsightIPedsRepository..cctor()

"Dotnet test" command should run successfully.

Can someone suggest me an alternative to fix this issue?

Comment: The two ways run differently. If you cannot provide a sample to reproduce it, there won’t be easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

i has a similar problem running tests on jenkins and visual studio 2019.
on jenkins failed but on vs2019 test works. on windows 10 cmd dotnet test **works**.

and running over WSL Ubuntu 18.04 equal to Jenkins.
sudo dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~myTest" **works**.
sudo dotnet test  **fail.**